# Sqlite Where clause with or shows deleted records

Tags: database, sqlite, ionic-framework, where-clause

I am using the following SQLite query to fetch data which is of type Farmer or Buyer.But it shows the deleted data also in that query.In the table, i am having the type as Farmer, Worker and Buyer in which i would like to take the data which is not deleted of type Farmer and Buyer.can anyone tell me what is wrong in that query pls.

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE user_id = 317 AND (is_deleted IS NULL or is_deleted != 'true') AND type = 'Farmer' OR type = 'Buyer' ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE ASC
```

Table Structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE user_id = 317 AND type != 'Worker' AND (is_deleted IS NULL or is_deleted != 'true') ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE ASC
```

Instead of using or you can use the above query.